# How can I easily bulk rename files with Perl?

Tags: perl, file, rename, bulk

I have a lot of files I'm trying to rename, I tried to make a regular expression to match them, but even that I got stuck on the files are named like:

> File Name 01
>
> File Name 100
>
> File Name 02
>
> File Name 03

etc, I would like to add a "0" (zero), behind any of file that are less than 100, like this:

> File Name 001
>
> File Name 100
>
> File Name 002
>
> File Name 003

The closest I got to so much as matching them was using this find -type d | sort -r | grep ' [1-9][0-9]$'  however I could not figure out how to replace them. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer me. Im on CentOS if that is of any help, all this is being done via SSH.

Comment: Do your filenames actually contain spaces?

Comment: Yes, they do they look like:

"File Name 01"
"File Name 101"

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "tools" available on the machine? Do you have perl, python, ruby or similar installed?

Comment: could you clarify which are the names of the files you're trying to match are, and which are the names you're trying to avoid matching? I'm a little confused here.

Comment: Perl (5.8.8) is on the machine, however python and ruby are not, I am familiar enough to go through yum and install them if necessary.

Comment: mpobrien; im trying to match files named like:

"Folder Name 12"
"Folder Name 120"

There is 2 words in the names the names are all the same, its just the numbers are different, in short I want to add a zero before any number under than 100, so Im trying to turn "File Name 10" into "File name 010", let me know if thats a bit more clear. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Are you running a program locally that must rename files on a remote system via SSH? Or can you install and run a program on the target system?

Comment: daotoad, its being done remotely via SSH. I can install stuff on the target system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
perl -e 'foreach $f (glob("File\\ Name*")) { $nf = $f; $nf =~ s/(\d+)$/sprintf("%03d",$1)/e; print `mv \"$f\" \"$nf\"`;}'
```

A bit overkill maybe, but it does what is asked.

Answer (score 10):

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/(\d+)/sprintf "%03d", $1/e'
```

or something like that, provided

1. You have GNU find and GNU xargs (for `-print0` and `-0`)
2. You have the 'rename' utility that comes with perl
3. There's only one group of digits in the filename. If there's more than one, then you need to do something with the regex to make it only match the number you want to reformat.

Comment: That's close to something I was going to suggest, using sed instead of xargs, so I'll +1 it.

Comment: I knew xargs was the way to go, I just couldn't write the exact command.

Comment: +1 For listing dependencies (it's possibly the rename utility you are referring to is one yum or apt-get away).

Comment: I've always been pissed that the cygwin perl distro doesn't include rename.

Answer (score 4):

Is this a one-time thing?  If so, I'm going to suggest something that might seem to be a cop out by many programmers here:

Pipe the output of your command (`find -type d | sort -r | grep ' [1-9][0-9]$'`) to a file and use an editor along with some global search/replace magic to create a script that does the renames.

Then throw away the script.

There's little fuss and little chance that you'll end up shooting yourself in the foot by having some attempt at a clever (but inadequately debugged) one-liner go off into the weeds on your files.

Comment: ++! Sometimes it is better to use a kludge you understand than to learn "deep magic".

Comment: +1 I think this sort of thing is often the most pragmatic solution for one off requirements

Comment: It may be a cop-out, but it's a safe cop-out...kudos.

Comment: A possible global search and replace magic in vim for this is `:s/^\(.*\)\(\d\d\)$/mv \1 \10\2/`

Comment: In Emacs you can open a directory listing, press C-x C-q, edit the filenames in the buffer (e.g. with search and replace, or any other command), and upon saving Emacs will rename the files.

Answer (score 2):

Run two commands, in this order:

```
$ rename 's/File Name (\d)$/File Name 0$1/' *
$ rename 's/File Name (\d\d)$/File Name 0$1/' *
```

First one renames everything less than 10 and prepends a zero. The second one renames everything less than 100 and prepends a zero. The result should be three digits for all filenames.

Comment: `rename` is a utility which comes with the standard perl distribution. I ran these under Linux Bash.

Answer (score 1):

In my debian it works well with rename, tested with 300 files.

```
 perl -e 'map `touch door$_.txt`, 1..300;'
 rename 's/(\d+)\.txt/sprintf("%03d.txt", $1)/e' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [mmv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mmv) is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something using perl or ruby.

put all this files in the same directory

```
dirlisting = DIR.entries('.')

dirListing.each do |file| 
 num = file.match(/\d+$/).to_i
 if num < 100
   find the position where start the number, with index and inject the 0 there.
 end
end
```

Comment: You should probably mention that this code is ruby and not perl

Comment: And that's why I said you should disambiguate the fact that the code is ruby.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use File::Copy;

my @files = glob 'File*Name*';

foreach my $filename (@files) {
    if ($filename =~ m`^.*File.*Name.*?(\d+)`) {
        my $number = $1;
        next if ($number > 99);
        rename $filename, sprintf("FileName%03d",$number);
    }
}
```

Comment: That renames `File Name 100` to `File Name 0100` which is not intended.

Comment: You were most certainly right.  Added some code to make it so that won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

if your remote has bash shell

```
for i in File*; 
do 
    case "${i##* }" in  [0-9][0-9] ) 
      echo  mv "$i" "${i% *} $(printf "%03d" ${i##* })" ;; 
    esac; 
done
```

remove "echo" to do actual renaming